# Water leakage through shower wall

Tags: water, leak

I have had water leaking through to the downstairs kitchen and have recently discovered a gap between the shower and wall, I was wondering whether mould could have grown inside the wall and that this could of contaminated the water supply I am very worried about this, I have a picture that I have found online that looks similar to this[image]

Comment: Do you have any way to get us photos of your actual situation?

Comment: I have no idea what "the picture you found online" shows.

Answer (score 1):

Because, as you suggested, the leak is likely caused by the gap between the shower and wall (and not a leak in the water supply pipe) it's a practical impossibility that mold in the wall somehow found its way into the supply pipe.  So, "No", mold didn't contaminate the water coming from the supply line.

Comment: But to the other part of your question, mold certainly could have grown inside the wall.

Answer (score 0):

This photo shows an improper installation--thus the gap.
To repair: remove faucet (twist off, to the left), remove the nipple (threaded part showing), and replace with a shorter nipple. Shorter by the length of the 'gap.' Once the faucet is reinstalled, caulk around it with clear silicone recommended for wet areas.